# WordPress CSS - how to resize and make it circular an image

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to customise a CSS in WordPress, but I am struggling on what to do...

as you can see in the following code, there is an "li" element with an image that has the following class: "func-um_user gravatar avatar avatar-40 um-avatar um-avatar-uploaded"

the image property set the dimension to **40px**...

```
<li id="menu-item-663" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-663">
<a href="#">First Last <img onerror="this.src='http://italiancrypto.it/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-member/assets/img/default_avatar.jpg';" src="http://italiancrypto.it/wp-content/uploads/ultimatemember/10/profile_photo-40.jpg?1515135317" class="func-um_user gravatar avatar avatar-40 um-avatar um-avatar-uploaded" width="25" height="25" alt="First Last" pagespeed_url_hash="3917330287" onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);" border-radius="40">
</a>
</li>
```

I need to create a custom CSS that **reset the picture to 30px** and that create a rounded border instead of square...

how can I do that?

Many thanks

Regards

Comment: Have a look at [Ask] & present some code which you've attempted to solve this problem with.

Comment: Please use width, height and border radius for css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this CSS:

```
.menu-item > a > img {
  width:         30px; 
  height:        30px; 
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

... and when that does not work, because of specificity (you did not post your CSS file), you can try this:

```
#masthead .menu-item > a > img {
  width:         30px; 
  height:        30px; 
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

... and when that does not work, use `!important` to force the CSS to work:

```
.menu-item > a > img {
  width:         30px!important; 
  height:        30px!important; 
  border-radius: 30px!important;
}
```

Here is a working example (selectors are simplified):

```css
img {
  width:         30px; 
  height:        30px; 
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<img onerror="this.src='http://italiancrypto.it/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-member/assets/img/default_avatar.jpg';" src="http://italiancrypto.it/wp-content/uploads/ultimatemember/10/profile_photo-40.jpg?1515135317" />
```

Or check: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aELYry

Comment: Avoid the use of !important

Comment: For Clyde (and others): !important is the only way to override inline styles. This is required when you cannot change the HTML but CAN change the CSS. The argument for NOT using !important is that it cannot be overridden. That is not true, as 'specificity' is still a thing when using !important. Please stop commenting on every answer with !important that it is bad practise (especially without an explanation). That is not helping anyone. Using !important is a proper solution when somebody asks for a CSS-only solution (and wants to override inline styles).

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your code.

```
<li id="menu-item-663" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-663">
<a href="#">First Last <img class="some" onerror="this.src='http://italiancrypto.it/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-member/assets/img/default_avatar.jpg';" src="http://italiancrypto.it/wp-content/uploads/ultimatemember/10/profile_photo-40.jpg?1515135317" class="func-um_user gravatar avatar avatar-40 um-avatar um-avatar-uploaded" width="25" height="25" alt="First Last" pagespeed_url_hash="3917330287" onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);" border-radius="40">
</a>
</li>
<style>
.some
{
//change dimensions as desired 
width:30px;
height:30px;
//this will give a rounded border
border-radius:50%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your class in the wordpress image class 40 to 30. And in order to round the border, used `border-radius: 30px` inline styling.

```
class="func-um_user gravatar avatar avatar-30 um-avatar um-avatar-uploaded"
```

Here is the full code

```html
<li id="menu-item-663" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-663">
  <a href="#">First Last <img onerror="this.src='http://italiancrypto.it/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-member/assets/img/default_avatar.jpg';" src="http://italiancrypto.it/wp-content/uploads/ultimatemember/10/profile_photo-40.jpg?1515135317" class="func-um_user gravatar avatar avatar-30 um-avatar um-avatar-uploaded" width="25" height="25"; alt="First Last" style="border-radius:30px";>
</a>
</li>
```

Hope this will meet your requirements.

Comment: The OP asks for a CSS only solution and apparently does not have access to the (generated) HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Follow code css

```css
.menu-item .func-um_user.gravatar {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 5px; //use to spacing between name and avatar
}
```